# CSS: set div height to height of the container, but leave 10px space

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a parent container and want it to be 300px in width and same height as the parent, but with a margin of 10 on each side. I found some answers that say, this is possible by setting `height: 100%;` `margin: 10px;` and `margin-bottom` to a negative value like `-20px` (to compensate for the 10px space on top and bottom). I tried it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <head></head>
    <body style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <div style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
            <div style="border:1px solid black;height:100%;width:300px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:-20px;">
                Hello world!
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. The div has the same height as the parent container, so it overlaps on the bottom ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <head></head>
    <body style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
        <div style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative">
            <div style="border:1px solid black;width:300px;position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;bottom:10px;">
                Hello world!
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ALSO BY JAVASCRIPT**

```
<div style="height:100%">
    <div class="child"></div>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
docHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
childHeight = docHeight-22; //2px due to borders
document.getElementsByClassName('child').style.height = childHeight;
```

CSS

`.child {padding:10px`}

Comment: I had to remove the `height:100%;` in the inner div, now your solution works, thanks!

Comment: I added also JS solution if you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
<head></head>
<body style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:10; background-color:#FF0000;">
        <div style="border:1px solid black;height:100%;width:300px; background:#0000FF;">
            Hello world!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

just remove the background color.

I add padding to the parent and remove the margins of the child

Comment: I just tried your code, but it doesn't work. Now the inner div has no space to the container.